# Why does my iPhone create so many 1**APPLE folders to store .JPG and .MOV?

Tags: iphone

I plugged in my iPhone into my Windows laptop, with a USB cable. Please see below.  1. Why does my iPhone create so many new separate folders?

2. Why do these folders contain merely .JPG and .MOV?

Doubtless I did not create them! I prefer just one folder to store .JPG and .MOV! Clicking on each of these 85 folders wastes time!

[image]

Comment: The structure is just not designed to go poking around in by hand… but Windows can't do it any other way. Mac users never see all that mess inside, so don't care about it.

Comment: Also, one folder with 1,000,000 files can be slower for the OS than 1000 folders, each with 1000 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you connect to transfer / backup, the new folder is created so old files are not overwritten by accident.

Those filenames usually include the current date / time to make sure they are unique.

If you find that a disadvantage, just look on here for how many have lost files and data…

Answer (score 1):

This is a folder structure [common to camera manufacturers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system). For example, on an SD used with a Canon camera, you also find a `DCIM` folder with subfolders `100CANON`, `101CANON`, …

A lot of image management apps understand this structure. It's not meant to be convenient to humans.

The reason why Apple creates so many of these folders is something we can only guess (unless there's an official document). [Solar Mike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437359/9849) has a good reason, though.